# Infinite square grid

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $n$ be an odd positive integer, and consider an infinite square grid. Prove that it is impossible to fill in one of $1,2$ or $3$ in every cell, which simultaneously satisfies the following conditions:
(1) Any two cells which share a common side does not have the same number filled in them.
(2) For any $1\times 3$ or $3\times 1$ subgrid, the numbers filled does not contain $1,2,3$ in that order be it reading from top to bottom, bottom to top, or left to right, or right to left.
(3) The sum of numbers of any $n\times n$ subgrid is the same.

**Attemp**: I think here's the general idea of the solution.

Firstly, if there are no $2$s on the grid, the claim is obvious.

Note that a number to the left and right of a number $2$ must be equal, similarly to top and bottom.

If some pattern of the form

.a.
b2b
.a.

appears, with $a \neq b$, then we note that the whole grid is uniquely determined (the corners must be $2$ and the pattern repeats). This case can again be easily solved.

Otherwise, for every occurence of $2$, all $4$ adjacent cells have the same number.

The key observation is that if we color the cells in white and black like a chessboard (adjacent cells have distinct colors), then one of the colors cannot contain the number $1$ and the cells of the other color cannot contain the number $3$.

WLOG, the white cells cannot contain the number $1$ and the black cells cannot contain the number $3$.

For every $n \times n$ subgrid, define the score as the difference between the number of white cells containing $2$ and the number of black cells containing $2$. Call a $n \times n$ subgrid white if the corners are white and black otherwise. All white $n \times n$ subgrid must have the same score while the score of a black $n \times n$ subgrid is $2$ less than a white $n \times n$ subgrid.

Suppose $(1, 1)$ is white and consider the subgrid with corners $(1, 1), (n, n)$ and the subgrid with corners $(1, 2), (n, n + 1)$. The score of the strip with corners $(1, 1)$ and $(n, 1)$ must be $2$ more than the score of the strip with corners $(1, n + 1)$ and $(n, n + 1)$. But the difference between the score of the strip with corners $(2, 1)$ and $(n + 1, 1)$ and the strip with corners $(2, n + 1)$ and $(n + 1, n + 1)$ is $-2$, so this implies all the squares $(1, 1), (1, n + 1), (n + 1, 1), (n + 1, n + 1)$ are marked with $2$. Repeating the same argument gives us $(2, 1), (2, n + 1), (n + 2, 1), (n + 2, n + 1)$ are marked with $2$, a contradiction to (1).

Any solution? My attempt doesn't have many fundamentals

Comment: I’m assuming that by $n\times n$ grid, you mean that with $n\geq2$?

Comment: Interesting puzzle but I only understood up to and including "all four numbers surrounding a $2$ must be the same".  Can you explain why the $1$s must be confined to one color black or white, and the $3$s must be confined to the other color?